# Disable landscape mode after returning from fullScreen video

Tags: android, jwplayer, android-orientation

I have a single activity application (Java). I have this line in the home fragment that disables landscape mode throughout the app:

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

The problem is, my fragment contains a video (I'm using JWPlayer). WHen I launch the video, fullscreen is forced:

```
mPlayerView.setFullscreen(true, true);
```

This causes the video to play in landscape mode. When the user clicks on the exit button in the video, the video is closed:

```
@Override
public void onFullscreen(FullscreenEvent fullscreenEvent) {
    if (!mPlayerView.getFullscreen()) {
        if (mPlayerView != null) {
            mPlayerView.stop();
        }
    }

}
```

When this happens, portrait mode is no longer disabled. How can I enable it again after returning from the fullscreen video?

I tried setRequestedOrientation again but that did not work.

Comment: there should be some callback in the video player class to determine when video is stopped. You should probably try setting orientation again

Comment: As far as I know the `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` must be called before you call `setContentView` method for your activity in `onCreate()` so when you shift back from landscape to potrait, your activity must be recreated, considering that make sure it is being called in the proper place.